# How to pivot my dataframe to exist on a single row only

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pivot my dataframe so that there is a single row and a single cell for each summary X metric comparison. I have tried pivoting this, but can't figure out a sensible index column.

Here is my current output.

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve my expected output?

[image]

To reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'summary': {0: 'mean',
  1: 'stddev',
  2: 'mean',
  3: 'stddev',
  4: 'mean',
  5: 'stddev'},
 'metric': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'C'},
 'value': {0: '2.0',
  1: '1.5811388300841898',
  2: '0.4',
  3: '0.5477225575051661',
  4: None,
  5: None}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), join columns together, convert to `index` and transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['value'])

df['g'] = df['summary'] + '_' + df['metric']

df = df.set_index('g')[['value']].T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  mean_A            stddev_A mean_B            stddev_B
0    2.0  1.5811388300841898    0.4  0.5477225575051661
```